# Sorting Multiple Lists

Tags: c#, sorting

I have 3 List containing : Index, Name, Age

Example:

```
List<int> indexList = new List<int>();
indexList.Add(3);
indexList.Add(1);
indexList.Add(2);
List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
nameList.Add("John");
nameList.Add("Mary");
nameList.Add("Jane");
List<int> ageList = new List<int>();
ageList.Add(16);
ageList.Add(17);
ageList.Add(18);
```

I now have to sort all 3 list based on the indexList.

How do I use .sort() for indexList while sorting the other 2 list as well

Comment: Is there any reason why you have these as different lists of related objects, instead of having them stored into one class with these as properties?

Comment: Make a `class` that contains Name and Age (and "index" if you really need it), then just sort them together using `.OrderBy`.

Comment: Dictionary/SortedList + anonymous class?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also see [help/tagging].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking at it the wrong way. Create a custom class:

```
class Person
{
     public int Index { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

Then, sort the `List<Person>` with the help of the `OrderBy` method from the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
List<Person> myList = new List<Person>() {
    new Person { Index = 1, Name = "John", Age = 16 };
    new Person { Index = 2, Name = "James", Age = 19 };
}
...

var ordered = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Index);
```

Also, you can read [Jon Skeet article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) about your *anti-pattern*.

Comment: [As as the almighty Jon Skeet once decreed](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)

Comment: @Aron, thanks. I updated my answer with the link to that article.

Answer (score 5):

Farhad's answer is correct and should be accepted.  But if you really have to sort three related lists in that way you could use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and OrderBy:

```
var joined = indexList.Zip(
        nameList.Zip(ageList, (n, a) => new { Name = n, Age = a }), 
            (ix, x) => new { Index = ix, x.Age, x.Name })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Index);
indexList = joined.Select(x => x.Index).ToList();
nameList = joined.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
ageList = joined.Select(x => x.Age).ToList();
```

All are ordered by the value in the index-list afterwards.